# How to add rolling 7 and 30 day columns to my daily count of distinct logins in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have half of my query that outputs the total distinct users logging in in my website for each day. But I need my third and fourth column to show the rolling week and month activity for my users.

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS Date = DATEADD(dd,-31,GETDATE())

SELECT CAST(ml.login AS Date) AS Date_Login
,COUNT(DISTINCT ml.email) AS Total
FROM database.members_log AS ml
WHERE 1=1
AND ml.login > @StartDate
GROUP BY CAST(ml.login AS Date)
ORDER BY CAST(ml.login AS Date) DESC
```

How could I complement my code to include 7-day & 30-day rolling count of distinct users

In other words: the unique amount of users who logged in within a given amount of time (Daily, Last 7 days, Last 30 days)

Comment: Can you provide a sample script with insert statements and the expected output

Comment: Please define 7-day and 30-day rolling count of distinct users.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just defined it in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're going for, but you can use window functions for rolling totals/counts. For example, if you wanted to keep your report of count by day, but also count by rolling week and month, you could do something like the following (using an intermediate CTE):

```
declare @StartDate AS Date = DATEADD(day, -31, getdate());

WITH
    -- this is your original query, with the ISO week and month number added.
    members_log_aggr(login_date,  year_nbr, iso_week_nbr, month_nbr, email_count) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            CAST(ml.login AS Date),
            DATEPART(YEAR, ml.login),
            DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, ml.login),
            DATEPART(MONTH, ml.login),
            COUNT(DISTINCT ml.email) AS Total
        FROM members_log AS ml
        WHERE 
            ml.login > @StartDate
        GROUP BY 
            CAST(ml.login AS Date),
            DATEPART(YEAR, ml.login),
            DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, ml.login),
            DATEPART(MONTH, ml.login)
    )
-- here, we use window functions for a rolling total of email count.
SELECT *, 
    SUM(email_count) OVER 
    (
        PARTITION BY year_nbr, iso_week_nbr 
        ORDER BY login_date
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS count_by_week,
    SUM(email_count) OVER
    (
        PARTITION BY year_nbr, month_nbr
        ORDER BY login_date
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) as count_by_month
FROM members_log_aggr
```

giving you this data:

```
+------------+----------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| login_date | year_nbr | iso_week_nbr | month_nbr | email_count | count_by_week | count_by_month |
+------------+----------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 2018-12-12 |     2018 |           50 |        12 |           1 |             6 |              7 |
| 2018-12-13 |     2018 |           50 |        12 |           1 |             6 |              7 |
| 2018-12-14 |     2018 |           50 |        12 |           1 |             6 |              7 |
| 2018-12-15 |     2018 |           50 |        12 |           1 |             6 |              7 |
| 2018-12-16 |     2018 |           50 |        12 |           2 |             6 |              7 |
| 2018-12-19 |     2018 |           51 |        12 |           1 |             1 |              7 |
| 2019-01-13 |     2019 |            2 |         1 |           2 |             2 |              3 |
| 2019-01-21 |     2019 |            4 |         1 |           1 |             1 |              3 |
+------------+----------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
```

A couple of additional notes:

- Your original query has `1=1` in your `WHERE` clause. You don't need that.
- There's no need to use abbreviations in your `DATEADD` function (or other date functions) For example, `DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE())` is more clearer and just as performant as `DATEADD(DD, -31, GETDATE())`
- It might be a good idea to replace `GETDATE()` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. They're the same function, but `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a SQL standard.

Comment: thats exactly what I need and love the additional notes at the end. I wish i could receive this feedback everytime!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "Conditional aggregates" can be used for this (basically just put a case expression inside an aggregate function) e.g.

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS date = DATEADD( dd, -31, GETDATE() )

SELECT
    CAST( ml.login AS date )   AS Date_Login

  , COUNT( DISTINCT CASE
        WHEN CAST( ml.login AS date ) >= DATEADD( dd, -7, CAST( GETDATE() AS date ) ) THEN ml.email
    END )                      AS in_week

  , COUNT( DISTINCT ml.email ) AS Total
FROM dbo.members_log AS ml
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ml.login > @StartDate
GROUP BY
    CAST( ml.login AS date )
ORDER BY
    CAST( ml.login AS date ) DESC
```

But as you are already filtering for just the past 31 days, I'm not sure what you mean by "rolling" week or "rolling" month.

Comment: what I need is really is daily loggins from unique users, unique loggins for the past 7 days & 30 days.
In addition to that I need the historical data for the past 30 days

Answer (score 1):

`count(distinct)` is quite tricky -- particularly for rolling averages.  If you are really looking for the unique users over a time span (rather than just the average of the daily unique visitors), then I think `apply` may be the simplest approach:

```
with d as (
      select cast(ml.login AS Date) AS Date_Login,
             count(distinct ml.email) AS Total
      from database.members_log ml
      where ml.login > @StartDate
      group by CAST(ml.login AS Date)
     )
select t.date_login, t.total, t7.total_7d, t30.total_30d
from t outer apply
     (select count(distinct ml2.email) as total_7d
      from database.members_log ml2
      where ml2.login <= dateadd(day, 1, t.date_login) and
            ml2.login > dateadd(day, -7, t.date_login)
     ) t7 outer apply
     (select count(distinct ml2.email) as total_30d
      from database.members_log ml2
      where ml2.login <= dateadd(day, 1, t.date_login) and
            ml2.login > dateadd(day, -30, t.date_login)
     ) t30
order by date_login desc;
```

The date arithmetic is my best understanding of what you mean by the rolling averages.  It includes the current day, but not the day  days ago.

Comment: Why use an outter apply instead  of cross join?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . Because `cross join` wouldn't work.  There is a correlation clause.